# arrange given line in a pattern

Tags: regex, perl, python-2.7, biopython

I have many files containing information about human.
pattern of information in each file is:

```
587. JARID2 antisense RNA 1
JARID2-AS1, Homo sapiens
Hs.664092: 16 sequences.

588. Transcribed locus
Homo sapiens
Hs.569392: 11 sequences.

589. Golgin A8 family, member G
GOLGA8G, Homo sapiens
Hs.169639: 11 sequences.
```

but I want them to be like that(tab separated):

```
587. JARID2 antisense RNA 1 JARID2-AS1, Homo sapiens    Hs.664092: 16 sequences.

588. Transcribed locus  Homo sapiens    Hs.569392: 11 sequences.

589. Golgin A8 family, member G GOLGA8G, Homo sapiens   Hs.169639: 11 sequences.
```

so that I can put them in a xl file proper way, manual arrangement would take a lot of time.

Comment: So, what you want is to replace newlines with tabs while preserving double newlines?

Answer (score 1):

with a perl oneliner:

```
perl -00 -wlpe 's/\n//gms' file.txt
```

Or if you truly want tab separated

```
perl -00 -wlpe 's/\n/\t/gms' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `([^\r\n])[\r\n]([^\r\n])` with `g` option
and replace w/ `$1 $2` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM9kS9)